# system.diagnostics.contracts.contract exists in both v4.0 v3.5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-contracts

I just upgraded to visual studio 2010 and installed the code contracts msi.  When I try to use it I get a compiler error that the system.diagnostics.contracts.contract dll exists in both the v3.5 and v4 framework.  Anyone know what I should do to resolve this?  Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact text of the error?

Comment: +1 The type 'System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract' exists in both 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft\Contracts\Contracts\v3.5\Microsoft.Contracts.dll' and 'c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll'

Answer (score 10):

If you're upgrading a .NET 3.5 project that uses contracts to .NET 4.0, make sure you remove your reference to the `Microsoft.Contracts` assembly.

The `Microsoft.Contracts` assembly provides code contracts for use in .NET 2.0 or 3.5 projects, but is provided by default with .NET 4.0 in `mscorlib`, so you don't need it. They both share the `System.Diagnostics.Contracts` namespace, so by having references to both at the same time, the compiler isn't able to figure out which one you're trying to use.

Comment: I removed the reference in all projects, but VS still shows the same errors... don't know why... removed, clean -> rebuild -> same result..

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by first installing it, thou that did not actually solve it.
Then removed the references and then I changed the project versions to 4.5 and after that, it worked.